# AWS Cloudformation template conditions and autoscaling config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am writing my first AWS Cloudformation template in Yaml. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to specify the number of instances created by an Autoscaling group based on two separate parameter inputs.

Example: User enters the volume of data indexed in GB from 1 to 3072 and it is saved as "data volume" parameter. Then the user enters the number of users of the network up to and it is saved as "usernumber". I then want to used to tell the ASG how many instances to create. So if there are 16 users and 2gb of data volume I want 2 instances and if there are 48 users and 500gb of data volume i want 10 instances and so on up to 21 instances.

Is something like this possible? Or am I stuck with only being able to allow the user to enter the number that they want as a single parameter?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is something like this possible?

You could probably create a number of [conditions in CFN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html), to account for **all possible combinations**. If you have only few allowed combinations, its should be doable.

For anything more complex, you need [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function** which could do any calculatons on your parameters and and launch your instance using AWS SDK.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful.

Comment: Are < and > valid symbols/arguments to use in these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I am trying to write

Create2Indexer:
!And
- !Equals
- !Ref 'NumberofUsers'
- <= '8'
- !Equals
- !Ref 'DailyIndexVolume'
- '>=300'
- !Equals
- !Ref 'DailyIndexVolume'
- < '600'
!OR
!AND
- !Equals
- !Ref 'NumberofUsers'
- > '16'
- !Equals
- !Ref 'DailyIndexVolume'
- < '300'